# Best way to store data for a weather application

Tags: android, database, data-storage

I'm learning Android by building applications and am currently developing a Weather application.

At the moment a user can type in the City and will get the relevant information. I want to expand it by allowing the user to store different weather forecast for multiple locations.

What is the best way to store the user selections in? SQLLiteDatabase or SharedPreferences? I want the user locations to be saved even when the process is killed, so when the user opens up the application the weather for those locations is still there and the user doesn't have to re-add them again.

Comment: SQLite stores the information just like any other database, doesn't matter if the process is killed or android is restarted. But there wouldn't be any new data in it. Do remember that

Answer (score 0):

If you are just storing the locations, I would recommend using `SharedPreferences`, a database seems like overkill. Just store the locations like this

```
prefs =  getSharedPreferences("your package name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//creates shared prefs
    String[] locations = .... 
    int number = locations.length;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putInt("numberOfLoactions", number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        edit.putString("location"+Integer.toString(i), locations[i]);
    }
    edit.commit();
```

And get them like this

```
    locations = new String[prefs.getInt("numberOfLocations");
for (int i = 0; i<locations.length; i++){
    locations[i] = prefs.getString("location" + Integer.toString(i), "error");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what kind of data about the location you want to save. If it's simply a  pair, such as matching a city name to a unique identifier, then `SharedPreferences` should suffice. If, however, you wish to store more information about the location (state, city, zip code, latitude, longitude, etc...) you will want to look into using a full relational database like SQLite. This will allow you to store complex data in an easy-to-manipulate form and will give you the ability to perform complex queries, such as getting all saved locations within a certain state.